Deriving orthogonal decomposition from semi-orthogonal decomposition
I've been scratching my head on this one.
It doesn't sound so difficult, but I can't find a satisfying solution.
Context
I am considering a system of $ P $ antenna subarrays (nodes), each equipped with $ M $ antenna elements and providing information (time or frequency samples, not important) through a sensor vector $x_p\in\mathcal{C}^{M\times1}$.
The equivalent system sensor vector can be computed as the concatenation:
$$
\mathbf{x} = \left[ \mathbf{x}_1^T \cdots \mathbf{x}_P^T \right]^T\in\mathcal{C}^{MP\times1}
$$
Through distributed processing methods (not detailled here), the system can compute the Hermitian correlation matrix $ \mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}} $ and an associated orthogonal decomposition:
$$
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}^H\in\mathcal{C}^{MP\times MP}
$$
with $\mathbf{D}=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{MP})$, and all matrices involved are of dimension $ MP \times MP $.
At this point this decomposition is considered known.
Goal:
I am interested on deriving a similar decomposition for the correlation matrices $\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p}$ associated to each subarray $p\leq P$. Due to computational costs, I don't want to go back from scratch to the associated sensing vector, correlation estimation, EVD ...
Current approach:
For a given $ p $, we consider the selection matrix:
$$
\mathbf{J}_p = \left[ 0_M  \cdots  \mathbf{I}_M \cdots  0_M \right]^T\in\mathcal{C}^{MP\times M}
$$
which is the zero matrix of size $ M \times MP $ whose block element of index $p$ has been replaced by the square identity matrix $ \mathbf{I}_M $.
Then the local sensing vector $ \mathbf{x}_p $ is expressed as:
$$
\mathbf{x}_p = \mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{C}^{M\times 1}
$$
Thus, the correlation matrix associated with subarray $ p $ and sensing vector $\mathbf{x}_p$ is expressed as:
$$
\mathbf{R}_p = \mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{R}_\mathbf{x} \mathbf{J}_p\in\mathcal{C}^{M\times M}
$$
Given the decomposition $ \mathbf{R}_\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}^H $, we have:
$$
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p} = \mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}^H \mathbf{J}_p
$$
$$
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p} = \left(\mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{U}\right) \mathbf{D} \left(\mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{U}\right)^H
$$
Setting $ \mathbf{U}_p = \mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{U} \in\mathcal{C}^{M\times MP}$, we thus have:
$$
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p} = \mathbf{U}_p \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}_p^H
$$
This decomposition is interesting, especially as :

$\mathbf{U}_p\mathbf{U}_p^H=\mathbf{J}_p^H \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{J}_p=\mathbf{I}_M$
$\mathbf{D}$ is diagonal

However, this does not match an orthogonal decomposition because:

$\mathbf{U}_p $ is not even square
$\mathbf{D} $ is of dimension $ PM $ instead of expected $ M$ for an EVD
$\mathbf{U}_p^H\mathbf{U}_p\neq\mathbf{I}_M$

Questions

How can I derive an eigenvalue decomposition of $\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p}$ from $ \mathbf{J}_p $, $ \mathbf{U}_p $ and $ \mathbf{D} $
What is the relation between the eigenvalues of all $\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}_p}$ and the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{x}}$ ?

Any help would be fantastic !
